# How define Server for Copy/Paste regions as input in R/Shiny?

Tags: html, r, shiny, textarea, shinydashboard

I have a shiny which can be used to overlap between query regions and a given data table (e.g. DF). I put two options for uploading query data `1)` as .bed format and `2)` inserting data as copy/paste.
The shiny works well with uploading *.bed* file but I am not sure how can I define **Server** for *copy/paste (text) data*.

Thank you in advance for any suggestion!

```
DF<- data.table(chr=c("chr1","chr2"),start=c(10,20),end=c(20,30))%>% setkey(chr, start, end) 
text<- data.table(chr=c("chr1","chr2"),start=c(15,25),end=c(15,30))%>% setkey(chr, start, end) 

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel (
      p(strong ("Find overlap between query file and data"),style = "color:blue;"),
      br(),
      selectInput("choose","Choose file source",choices = c("file","text"),selected = "file"),
      conditionalPanel("input.choose=='file'",
                   fileInput("query.file", "Upload genomic coordinates in .bed 
                             format:",multiple = F,accept = ".bed")),
      conditionalPanel("input.choose=='text'",
                   textAreaInput("query.text", "Enter genomic coordinates:")),
      actionButton("run", "run"),
      width = "2"),
  mainPanel(
    dataTableOutput("DFtable"),
    dataTableOutput("overlap_table"))
  )
)

server <- function (input, output, session) {

  ## Read user .bed file
  user_query.file <- reactive({
  req(input$query.file)
  ext <- tools::file_ext(input$query.file$name)
  switch(ext,
       bed = fread(input$query.file$datapath,header=F)%>% 
         dplyr::rename (chr =V1, start=V2, end=V3) %>% setkey(chr, start, end)%>% unique()
    )
  })

  ## overlapping between query file and table
  overlap <- eventReactive(input$run, {
  req(input$run)
  withProgress(message = 'Analysis in progress', value = 0, {
  query.overlap<- foverlaps(user_query.file() ,DF,  nomatch = 0) %>% 
    unique()
    })
  })

  ## output
  output$DFtable<- renderDataTable({ DF })
  output$overlap_table <- renderDT({overlap () }) 

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Desire out put using TEXT input option:

```
chr start end i.start i.end

chr1    15  15      10    20 
chr2    25  30      20    30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure on how your copied text looks like, but assuming something like:

```
chr,start,end
chr1,10,20
chr4,34,56
```

All you need is to parse the text contents of the UI input and assigned it to DF variable. Your `run` event handler could look like:

```
  ## overlapping between query file and table
  overlap <- eventReactive(input$run, {
    req(input$run)
    
    #Requiring text input and parsing it
    req(input$query.text)
    DF <- data.table(read.csv(text=input$query.text)) %>% setkey(chr, start, end)

    withProgress(message = 'Analysis in progress', value = 0, {
      query.overlap<- foverlaps(text ,DF,  nomatch = 0) %>%
        unique()
    })
  })
```

Then when clicking on the `run` button, the analysis is executed and the overlap reactive value is updated. If the comparison is always between file and text provided, you should also include a `req(user_query.file())` to ensure the file has been provided and correctly parsed.